# Decoding an Int32 in Java for the Mantissa (Significant Bits) using bitwise logic

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, ieee-754

I know this sounds like a question that has been asked before but in my case, I am being asked to do some bitwise logic for an int32 value and interpreting that as a floating-point, not converting the value to a floating-point but interpreting the binary value associated with it as a float and finding the significant bits (also known as the mantissa) in the set. I am using IEE-754 standard for the conversion.

The instructions are:

"Use a bitmask to isolate the significant digits, then use a loop to iterate over each digit, shifting as necessary to get them in the LSB position, and multiplying by the appropriate power-of-2. The result will be a float without an exponent.
Don't forget to include the "hidden" bit!
Consider a loop that counts down -- craft it carefully and it will let you start at the LSB and work your way to the MSB."

From my understanding of this, I crafted this abomination

```
    public static float decodeSignificantDigits(int value) {
    int mask = 0x007FFFFF;
    int significantBits = value & mask;
    float significantDigits = 0;
    
    for (int i = -23; i <= 0; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            significantDigits += (significantBits >> 1) * Math.pow(2, i);
            
        } else {
            significantDigits += 1 * Math.pow(2, i);
        }
        
    }
    System.out.println(significantDigits);
    return significantDigits;
}
```

I think I am on the right track here but I just can not visualize how to get this to work correctly.

The main idea is to get the following tests to pass:

```
@Test
void testWhenAllOnes() {
    int bits = 0b00000000011111111111111111111111;
    int bitsWithExpoentZero = 0b00111111111111111111111111111111;
    assertEquals(Float.intBitsToFloat(bitsWithExpoentZero), FloatDecoder.decodeSignificantDigits(bits), TOL);
}

@Test
void testWhenMsbOfSignificantDigitsIsOneRestZeroes() {
    int bits = 0b00000000010000000000000000000000;
    int bitsWithExpoentZero = 0b00111111110000000000000000000000;
    assertEquals(Float.intBitsToFloat(bitsWithExpoentZero), FloatDecoder.decodeSignificantDigits(bits), TOL);
}

@Test
void testWhenLsbOfSignificantDigitsIsOneRestZeroes() {
    int bits = 0b00000000000000000000000000000001;
    int bitsWithExpoentZero = 0b00111111100000000000000000000001;
    assertEquals(Float.intBitsToFloat(bitsWithExpoentZero), FloatDecoder.decodeSignificantDigits(bits), TOL);
}
```

I was also informed not to use Integer.toBinaryString() for my solution.

Comment: `Math.pow(2, i)` don't do this. Use `1 << i` instead

Comment: Better, some of my tests work now. Why does that work though?

Comment: Because it is 100% accurate and FP isn't.

Comment: Sure, that is apparent but I mean how does shifting 1 to n number of bits work? I am sure it is a stupid question for someone experienced, but I am not experienced.